# Python - Search for Word In Line, Count it, Add It

Tags: python, search, text, find, lines

I'm pretty sure I'm over thinking this and there's a simple outcome for it, but I just can't seem to put it all together.

I'm looking for a kind of a search method. I'd like a Python script search a text file for a keyword and count how many lines it appears on. Though if the keyword comes up on a single line multiple times, I'd like to still only count it once.

Long story short; If a keyboard comes up on a single line, I want it to count that line and add it to what will be a math equation.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: With which part of this problem are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the following function.

```
def lcount(keyword, fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        return sum([1 for line in fin if keyword in line])
```

Now if you want to know the number of lines containing "int" in "foo.cpp", you do:

```
print lcount('int', 'foo.cpp')
```

An alternative that you can do on the command line (if you are on an appropriate platform) is:

```
grep int foo.cpp | wc -l
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew I wasn't far off. You were a big help. Thanks. :)

Comment: You could make the grep line even more concise as
`grep -c int foo.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

A non-Python Unix solution is fairly immediate:

- "search a text file for a keyword" is a *grep*
- "count how many lines" is a *wc*

Do you have difficulty implementing the essence of either of these in Python?

Comment: I had thought of those, but unfortunately am running on a Windows system and hadn't know if there were alternatives to it. Plus, I'm trying to keep it as close to 'Python Only' as possible. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
def kwdCount(textContent, keyword):
    lines=textContent.split("\n")
    count=len([1 for line in lines if line.find(keyword)!=-1])
    return count

>>> yourTextFile="hello world\n some words here\n goodbye world"
>>> kwdCount(ourTextFile,"world")
    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming f is the file object,

```
lines = f.readlines()
print len([line for line in lines if keyword in line])
```